# Runge-Kutta method for Simple pendulum in java

Tags: java, runge-kutta

I'm trying to study Runge-Kutta method and apply on a simple pendulum. Using a timestep dt=0.1 (h=0.1) the pendulum increses energy of 1% every period... while in this site: 
[link](https://www.myphysicslab.com/pendulum/pendulum/pendulum-en.html) 
decreses energy about 0.01% What am I doing wrong? 
There is a software where can I compare my camculated values? thanks

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


class Sistema{
    double g=10;//9.81;
    double m1 = 1;
    double th1 = Math.PI/2;
    double w1=0;
    double L1=1;

    double dt=0.001;

    final int N = 2;

    double energiaIniziale, yPotenziale0;

    ArrayList<Point2D.Double> tracciato = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();

    public Sistema(){
        double y0 = getY();

        yPotenziale0 = m1*L1;
        energiaIniziale = energiaCinetica()+energiaPotenziale();

        System.out.println("y0:"+y0);
        System.out.println("y:"+yPotenziale0 + " Tot."+energiaIniziale+" = C:"+energiaCinetica()+" P:"+energiaPotenziale());

    }

    synchronized ArrayList<Point2D.Double> getTracciato(){
        return tracciato;
    }

    synchronized double energiaCinetica(){
        return m1*L1*L1*w1*w1/2;
    }

    synchronized double energiaPotenziale(){
        return m1*g*yPotenziale0+g*m1*getY();
    }

    synchronized double getX(){ 
        double x1 = L1*Math.sin(th1);
        return x1; 
    }

    synchronized double getY(){ 
        double y1 = -L1*Math.cos(th1);
        return y1; 
    }



    void simulate(){

        synchronized(this){
            double yin[] = new double[N];
            yin[0] = th1;
            yin[1] = w1;
            double yout[] = runge_kutta(0, yin, dt);
            this.th1 = yout[0];
            this.w1 = yout[1];

            //System.out.println(""+Math.toDegrees(th1)+" "+w1);

            tracciato.add(new Point2D.Double(getX(), getY()));
        }
    }

    double[] derivs(double xin, double yin[])
    {
        /*
            yin[0] = th1[i];
            yin[1] = w1[i];
            yin[2] = th2[i];
            yin[3] = w2[i];
         */

        double dydx[] = new double[N];
        /* function to fill array of derivatives dydx at xin */

        dydx[0] = yin[1]; 
        dydx[1] = -g/L1*Math.sin(th1);

        return dydx;

    }

    double[] runge_kutta(double xin, double yin[], double h)
    {
        double yout[] = new double[N];
        /* fourth order Runge-Kutta - see e.g. Numerical Recipes */

        int i;
        double hh, xh;
        double dydx[] = new double[N];
        double dydxt[] = new double[N];
        double yt[] = new double[N];
        double k1[] = new double[N];
        double k2[] = new double[N];
        double k3[] = new double[N];
        double k4[] = new double[N];

        hh = 0.5*h;
        xh = xin + hh; 

        dydx = derivs(xin, yin); /* first step */
//      System.out.print("a:");
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        {
            k1[i] = h*dydx[i];
            yt[i] = yin[i] + 0.5*k1[i];
//          System.out.printf(" %5.2f ",k1[i]);
        }

        dydxt = derivs(xh, yt); /* second step */ 
//      System.out.print("\nb:");
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            k2[i] = h*dydxt[i];
            yt[i] = yin[i] + 0.5*k2[i];
//          System.out.printf(" %5.2f ",k2[i]);
        }   

        dydxt = derivs(xh, yt); /* third step */
//      System.out.print("\nc:");
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            k3[i] = h*dydxt[i];
            yt[i] = yin[i] + k3[i];
//          System.out.printf(" %5.2f ",k3[i]);
        }

        dydxt = derivs(xin + h, yt); /* fourth step */
//      System.out.print("\nd:");
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            k4[i] = h*dydxt[i];
            yout[i] = yin[i] + k1[i]/6. + k2[i]/3. + k3[i]/3. + k4[i]/6.;
//          System.out.printf(" %5.2f ",k4[i]);
        }
//      System.out.println();
        return yout;

    }
}

class Pannello extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener{

    double x[];
    double y[];
    int offX, offY;
    double scale;
    final int DIM_BARRA_EN = 400;

    Sistema sistema;

    public Pannello(Sistema sistema){
        this.sistema=sistema;
        x = new double[2];
        y = new double[2];
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int raggioPallina=20;
        offX=this.getWidth()/2;
        offY=this.getHeight()/2;
        scale=(getHeight()-100)/sistema.L1/2;
        ArrayList<Point2D.Double> tracciato;
        synchronized(sistema){

            x[0]=sistema.getX()*scale;
            y[0]=-sistema.getY()*scale;
            tracciato = sistema.getTracciato();
        }


        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;        
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));

        for(int i=0; i<tracciato.size()-1; i++){
            int x1 = (int) (tracciato.get(i).x*scale+offX);
            int y1 = (int) (-tracciato.get(i).y*scale+offY);
            int x2 = (int) (tracciato.get(i+1).x*scale+offX);
            int y2 = (int) (-tracciato.get(i+1).y*scale+offY);
            int c = (int) (255.0/tracciato.size()*i);
            //          System.out.println("i: "+i+" colore: "+c+" n."+sistema.tracciato.size()*i);
            g2.setPaint(new Color(c, 0, 0));
            g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        }

        g2.setPaint(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));

        //bracci e palline
        g.drawLine(offX,offY, (int)x[0]+offX,(int)y[0]+offY);
        g.fillOval((int)x[0]-raggioPallina/2+offX, (int)y[0]-raggioPallina/2+offY, raggioPallina, raggioPallina);

        //energia
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
        g2.setPaint(new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
        g.fillRect(10,10,DIM_BARRA_EN,10);//tot
        g2.setPaint(new Color(0f, 1f, 0f));

        double e = sistema.energiaCinetica();
        double v = sistema.energiaPotenziale();
        double m = sistema.energiaIniziale;
        g.fillRect(10,20,(int)(e/sistema.energiaIniziale*DIM_BARRA_EN),10);//cinetica
        g2.setPaint(new Color(1f, 0f, 0f));
        g.fillRect(10+(int)(e/sistema.energiaIniziale*DIM_BARRA_EN),20,
                (int)(v/sistema.energiaIniziale*DIM_BARRA_EN),10);//potenziale


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

        x[0]=(double)arg0.getX()-offX;
        y[0]=(double)arg0.getY()-offY;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true){
            sistema.simulate();

            System.out.format("EnIni:%8.2f Tot.%8.2f = C: %8.2f P: %8.2f\n",
                    sistema.energiaIniziale,
                    sistema.energiaCinetica()+sistema.energiaPotenziale(),
                    sistema.energiaCinetica(),sistema.energiaPotenziale());

            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (sistema.dt*1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}


public class Pendolo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        Sistema s = new Sistema();

        Pannello p = new Pannello(s);
        p.setBounds(0,0,600,600);
        frame.add(p);
        p.addMouseMotionListener(p);
        new Thread(p).start();



        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

[Reference](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/runge-kutta-method-for-simple-pendulum-in-java.914533/)

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to reduce the code to the bare minimum to display a table of time, state and energy on the console. -- As far as I can see, your RK4 code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the results as per the theory of RK4 you should use the state as given in the argument to compute the derivatives, not the global variable of the model state at the last sample point.

```
double[] derivs(double xin, double yin[])
{
    double dydx[] = new double[N];
    /* function to fill array of derivatives dydx at xin */

    dydx[0] = yin[1]; 
    dydx[1] = -g/L1*Math.sin(yin[0]);
    /*        Error was here ^^^^^^^     */

    return dydx;
}
```

---

Runge-Kutta methods are made for functions `f(x,y)` in `y'(x)=f(x,y(x))` that only should depend on exactly these input variables or on constants that are global to the whole integration.

Your previous code introduces an error of order `h` in each of the evaluations of `derivs` as you use `y[0]` instead of `y[0]+0.5*k1[0]` etc. which translates into a quadratic error at the level of the RK step. This means the method is as good as the explicit Euler method, has global error order 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but th1 is updated after the call to runge kutta method. So, in this example, is the same thing...

Comment: No, it is not. The value of it changes inside the RK4-step, take a debugger or insert a debug print-out to compare `yin[0]` to `th1`. Only with the changing value do you get an order 4 method, with the step-constant value you only get an order 1 method. The errors you observed confirm that.